# ClaimsPrincipal Azure Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

This is a generalized concept question concerning obtaining information of the user in the bot chat. Preferably this would be through OpenID and to start with using Microsoft Accounts. We would want to be able to read User Display Name, User Email address, User Group Membership, etc. What is the best way to obtain this information in Azure Bot Framework? In MVC using OpenID to obtain ClaimsPrincipal is easy, but can this concept be used in Azure Bot Framework and are there any examples of this process?

Comment: I have read and tested this bot sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp. I can see the token, but nothing else. Is this going down the right path and does this authentication mechanism allow reading the additional user claims attributes?

Comment: I believe the solution I will take is to obtain the token from OAuth AD from the sample above and then using that token to query MS Graph API to obtain information about the user. Once I have this working I will post what the solution looks like here.

Answer (score 1):

There was a lot that went into this, but essentially I used an OAuth Connection on the Bot service to send the user to AADv2 endpoint to obtain the token. I then used that token to send to the GraphServiceClient method (part of Nuget package Microsoft.Graph) to obtain User information. This was granted by giving the app in Azure AD MS Graph User.Read API permissions.